# how can i change bytes of string that look the same

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

I want to check file name length

When i check the length of file name I got from mac is different from the length of the name I typed in IDE(Intellij).

So, I took the bytes of the string and printed it to the console, but it was different.
The case I want is the length as if i typed in IDE.
Is this possible?
How can i change the java bytes of string from macString to IDEString

```java
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileNameFromMac = "스크린샷.png";
        String typedInIDE = "스크린샷.png";

        System.out.println("File Name From Mac Length : " + fileNameFromMac.length());
        System.out.println("typedInIDE : " + typedInIDE.length());

        byte[] fileNameFromMacBytes = fileNameFromMac.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        byte[] typedInIDEBytes = typedInIDE.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        for(byte b : fileNameFromMacBytes) {
            System.out.print(b);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(byte b : typedInIDEBytes) {
            System.out.print(b);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a difference in [Unicode normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence). After normalizing to the same form, they will both have the same length (and the same bytes):

```
import java.text.Normalizer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fromMac = "스크린샷.png";
        String fromIDE = "스크린샷.png";

        System.out.println("From Mac length: " + fromMac.length());
        System.out.println("From IDE length: " + fromIDE.length());

        String normFromMac = Normalizer.normalize(fromMac, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        String normFromIDE = Normalizer.normalize(fromIDE, Normalizer.Form.NFD);

        System.out.println("Normalized from Mac length: " + normFromMac.length());
        System.out.println("Normalized from IDE length: " + normFromIDE.length());
    }
}
```

This yields the following output:

```
From Mac length: 14
From IDE length: 8
Normalized from Mac length: 14
Normalized from IDE length: 14
```

See the [Oracle Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html) for more information.

Comment: Hello, @김상엽  if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @HariHaravelan
I was almost new to stack overflow, so I didn't know much, but thank you for letting me know.